# Replace next 14 characters with X after the first 10 characters

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span tag with 34 randomly generated letters and numbers. I will like 14 characters after the first 10 characters to be replaced with X. Please how can this be done with javascript? Thanks.

From This:

```
<span>1KThBTGGQgT7VsZjYSgucdHMCUJrw5UdrJ</span>
```

To This:
1KThBTGGQgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCUJrw5UdrJ

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm new to coding, i have no idea about how to go about it.

Comment: @user3261093 You should know how to use a normal for loop. Loop through the string, and check every index. If the index is between 14 and 24, replace the character with X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can probably also do this with regex which might be a better solution

```js
//To This: 1KThBTGGQgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCUJrw5UdrJ

let text = document.querySelector('span')

let left = text.innerText.substr(0,10)
let center = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
let right = text.innerText.substr(24)

let newText = left + center + right

text.innerText = newText
```

```html
<span>1KThBTGGQgT7VsZjYSgucdHMCUJrw5UdrJ</span>
```

Comment: The characters in the <span> tag is generated by a very complex javascript code so this didn't work.

Comment: I got it to work with the javascript that created the random characters. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Component = () => {
  const text = "1KThBTGGQgT7VsZjYSgucdHMCUJrw5UdrJ";

  const modifiedContent = text.slice(0, 10) + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" + text.slice(24);

  return <span>{modifiedContent}</span>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**